# Is it possible to use a dedicated IP as source IP?

Tags: java

The title may sound a bit odd but I wanted to keep the title short.

So I have here a Socket which connects to some server for testing purpose.

Now when I get the IP from the client socket (server side) it will give me one IP (external one).

But I have another IPv4 dedicated IP, can I use that as source?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question.  Two machines are connecting through a TCP socket.  The client machine has 2 routable IP addresses.  When the client connects on one of those IP addresses to the server you want to make another connection back to the client on the other IP address?  What's confusing is the line "...can I use that as source?"  Source for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a Socket to originate on a particular IP/interface, you should be able to `bind()` it to the appropriate address before issuing the `connect()`.